# lighthouse error when analysing site method <= browser ERR:error Animation.resolveAnimation

Tags: chromium, devtools, lighthouse

I tried several times.
It looks that this issue appeared when some changes in lighthouse or chromium were added.

The same issue when running from Chrome plugin and from command line
$ lighthouse https://somesite.somedomain

How can I find what exactly is causing issue or which test so I can disable it to get other results?

```
 <pre>
      ChromeLauncher Waiting for browser. +0ms
      ChromeLauncher Waiting for browser... +1ms
      ChromeLauncher Waiting for browser..... +506ms
      ChromeLauncher Waiting for browser.....✓ +3ms
      config:warn IFrameElements gatherer requested, however no audit requires it. +304ms
      config:warn FormElements gatherer requested, however no audit requires it. +0ms
      status Connecting to browser +39ms
      status Resetting state with about:blank +17ms
      status Benchmarking machine +15ms
      status Initializing… +1s
      status Running defaultPass pass CSSUsage, JsUsage, ViewportDimensions, RuntimeExceptions, ConsoleMessages, AnchorElements, ImageElements, LinkElements, MetaElements, ScriptElements, IFrameElements, FormElements, MainDocumentContent, GlobalListeners, AppCacheManifest, Doctype, DOMStats, OptimizedImages, PasswordInputsWithPreventedPaste, ResponseCompression, TagsBlockingFirstPaint, FontSize, EmbeddedContent, RobotsTxt, TapTargets, Accessibility, TraceElements, InspectorIssues, SourceMaps +14ms
      status Resetting state with about:blank +0ms
      status Setting up network for the pass trace +7ms
      status Cleaning browser cache +2ms
      status Beginning devtoolsLog and trace +43ms
      status Loading page & waiting for onload +45ms
      status Gathering in-page: CSSUsage +3s
      status Gathering in-page: JsUsage +0ms
      status Gathering in-page: ViewportDimensions +0ms
      status Gathering in-page: RuntimeExceptions +0ms
      status Gathering in-page: ConsoleMessages +0ms
      status Gathering in-page: AnchorElements +1ms
      status Gathering in-page: ImageElements +0ms
      status Gathering in-page: LinkElements +0ms
      status Gathering in-page: MetaElements +0ms
      status Gathering in-page: ScriptElements +0ms
      status Gathering in-page: IFrameElements +0ms
      status Gathering in-page: FormElements +0ms
      status Gathering in-page: MainDocumentContent +0ms
      status Gathering in-page: GlobalListeners +0ms
      status Gathering in-page: AppCacheManifest +0ms
      status Gathering in-page: Doctype +0ms
      status Gathering in-page: DOMStats +0ms
      status Gathering in-page: OptimizedImages +0ms
      status Gathering in-page: PasswordInputsWithPreventedPaste +0ms
      status Gathering in-page: ResponseCompression +0ms
      status Gathering in-page: TagsBlockingFirstPaint +0ms
      status Gathering in-page: FontSize +0ms
      status Gathering in-page: EmbeddedContent +0ms
      status Gathering in-page: RobotsTxt +0ms
      status Gathering in-page: TapTargets +0ms
      status Gathering in-page: Accessibility +0ms
      status Gathering in-page: TraceElements +0ms
      status Gathering in-page: InspectorIssues +0ms
      status Gathering in-page: SourceMaps +0ms
      status Gathering trace +0ms
      status Gathering devtoolsLog & network records +475ms
      status Gathering: CSSUsage +7ms
      status Gathering: JsUsage +194ms
      status Gathering: ViewportDimensions +16ms
      status Gathering: RuntimeExceptions +2ms
      status Gathering: ConsoleMessages +1ms
      status Gathering: AnchorElements +1ms
      status Gathering: ImageElements +130ms
      status Gathering: LinkElements +3s
      status Gathering: MetaElements +6ms
      status Gathering: ScriptElements +3ms
      status Gathering: IFrameElements +17ms
      status Gathering: FormElements +4ms
      status Gathering: MainDocumentContent +29ms
      status Gathering: GlobalListeners +15ms
      status Gathering: AppCacheManifest +2ms
      status Gathering: Doctype +2ms
      status Gathering: DOMStats +1ms
      status Gathering: OptimizedImages +7ms
      status Gathering: PasswordInputsWithPreventedPaste +192ms
      status Gathering: ResponseCompression +2ms
      status Gathering: TagsBlockingFirstPaint +3ms
      status Gathering: FontSize +2ms
      status Gathering: EmbeddedContent +1s
      status Gathering: RobotsTxt +3ms
      status Gathering: TapTargets +45ms
      status Gathering: Accessibility +143ms
      status Gathering: TraceElements +3s

      **method <= browser ERR:error Animation.resolveAnimation  +27ms
      method <= browser ERR:error Animation.resolveAnimation  +2ms
      method <= browser ERR:error Animation.resolveAnimation  +14ms
      method <= browser ERR:error Animation.resolveAnimation  +0ms
      method <= browser ERR:error Animation.resolveAnimation  +1ms
      method <= browser ERR:error Animation.resolveAnimation  +0ms
      method <= browser ERR:error Animation.resolveAnimation  +1ms
      method <= browser ERR:error Animation.resolveAnimation  +1ms
      method <= browser ERR:error Animation.resolveAnimation  +1ms**
    </pre>
```

Comment: you will have to give us a URL to test on, but this looks like a bug. Never heard of this but from what I can see it appears to be some devTools command. This would probably be better raised in [Lighthouse on Github](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse)

Comment: I had similar issue on two sites.
For example: https://www.biuronet.com

Answer (score 3):

**not a proper answer just too much to put in a comment**

It is all related to https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Animation/#method-resolveAnimation

Which appears to be closely related to an error that people are getting `Error code: STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION` (as I get that when running it through DevTools Lighthouse).

This error started appearing a couple of months ago.

**As such I would say this appears to be a [bug with chromium](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse/issues/11654) and not lighthouse.**

Unfortunately until they patch whatever is causing it there is nothing you can do other than roll back to a previous chromium version and possibly Lighthouse version if not compatible (assuming you are using the [Lighthouse CLI](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse))